# When is it necessary to check_url()?

Tags: 7, security

When is it necessary to use check_url()? For instance, if I create a login link by putting the code below in the body of a block, which of the 3 check_url() calls are necesssary and which ones are not?

```
<?php print '<a href="/user?destination=';
if ((preg_match('#^user(?:$|/login$|/logout$|/register$)#', 
  check_url(current_path())) && !isset($_GET['destination'])) || 
  preg_match('#^user(?:$|/login$|/logout$|/register$)#', 
  drupal_get_normal_path(check_url($_GET['destination']))) || 
  drupal_get_http_header('Status') === '404 Not Found') {
    print 'homepage';
} 
else {
  print drupal_get_path_alias(check_url(reset(drupal_get_destination()))); 
}
print '">Login</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just use [l($text, $path, array $options = array())](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) you can simplify your code and it will take care of check_url for you.

Comment: Thanks for this but in general is check_url only necessary for text that is outputted? For instance, in my admittedly convoluted code, is it only necessary in else { print... and the previous 2 times it is unnecessary? I.e. is it only necessary IF the result will be printed somewhere, but not necessary if it is to satisfy some conditions?

Comment: check_url basically checks for dangerous protocols in the url and escapes any special characters as HTML entities for output. Normally it's not needed unless outputting a raw external / absolute URL. For relative URLs, Drupal adds the base url automatically.